# Discriminate closed-chain from open-chain

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, topology, biophysics, polymers

I have two classes of chains: closed-chains where a random path ends near where it starts (ie. loop), and open-chains without this restriction (ie. random walk). These chains are a directed graph connecting discrete points ($x, y, z)$ (ie. $n$ points, $n-1$ vectors) with sequential order.

One way I have tried to discriminate these two chains is by analyzing the start-end distances. Expectedly, the start-end distance of closed-chains is small, while the start-end distance of open-chains is large. There is a noticeable overlap that will result in false-positives/false-negatives.

What are some other metrics one might discriminate these two types of chains? I thought perhaps angular momentum might be useful, but it is unclear how to derive a metric more robust than this start-end distance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why isn't the start-end distance zero for the closed loops?

Comment: Good catch. The endpoint are not necessarily overlapping with start points - so the trivial check of verifying the coordinates of start-points & end-points is not possible.

Comment: ah I see now. I wouldn't be able to come up with a better metric myself. It's hard to distinguish those two cases because a random walk that randomly ends up near its starting position is identical to a closed loop.

Comment: You restrict the loops to end where they start? Or you just do random walks and then see which ones end up being a loop?

Comment: No I don't, the loop generation is based on an algorithm described here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/49/27/275202/meta

Comment: If you are determining which walk is which a priori then what is the point of finding some other method to discriminate them?

Comment: The simulation is merely an illustration, and used to inform my strategy. In a project I have been working on, we don't know which paths are closed-chain/open-chain and I'm identifying strategies to do so.